# share link on facebook, how to reinitialize fb obj

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am working on a project which requires the functionality to show facebook, twitter, google+ icon in a popup to share a link.

Twitter and Google+ works fine for me.
But in case of facebook, the share icon shows when i loads the popup first time, but it does not show after i loads the popup again until refresh the main page.

I think it is because, fb obj already initialized at the first time of loading popup prevents to reinitialize when popup reloads.

Can anyone suggest, how i can fix this.

I used following code:

***Google+***

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo 'dynamically_created_link_with_querystring';?>" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;">
<img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-16.png" alt="Share on Google+"/></a>
```

***Twitter***

```
<script>
window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

  t._e = [];
  t.ready = function(f) {
    t._e.push(f);
  };

  return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
</script>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=<?php echo 'dynamically_created_link_with_querystring';?>" >
<img src="images/Twitter_logo_blue_16.png"/></a>
```

***Facebook***

```
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo "dynamically_generated_link_with_querstring";?>" data-layout="icon"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the above issue using the following code:

***New Facebook Code***

```
<a href="javascript:fbShare('<?php echo dynamically_generated_link_with_querystring ?>', 520, 350)">
<img src="images/fb_icon.png" height="32"width="32"/>
</a>
<script>
function fbShare(url, winWidth, winHeight) {
    var winTop = (screen.height / 2) - (winHeight / 2);
    var winLeft = (screen.width / 2) - (winWidth / 2);
    url = encodeURIComponent(url);
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=' + url, 'sharer', 'top=' + winTop + ',left=' + winLeft + ',toolbar=0,status=0,width=' + winWidth + ',height=' + winHeight);
}
</script>
```

***old Facebook code***

```
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo "dynamically_generated_link_with_querstring";?>" data-layout="icon"></div>
```